# Modify an existing RDD without replicating memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to implement a distributed algorithm using Spark. It is a computer vision algorithm with tens of thousands of images. The images are divided into "partitions" that are processed in a distributed fashion, with the help of a master process. The pseudocode goes something like this:

```
# Iterate
for t = 1 ... T
  # Each partition
  for p = 1 ... P
    d[p] = f1(b[p], z[p], u[p])
  # Master
  y = f2(d)
  # Each partition
  for p = 1 ... P
    u[p] = f3(u[p], y)

# Each partition
for p = 1 ... P
  # Iterate
  for t = 1 ... T
    z[p] = f4(b[p], y, v[p])
    v[p] = f5(z[p])
```

where `b[p]` contains the pth partition of the images which is a numpy ndarray, `z[p]` contains some function of `b[p]` and also a numpy ndarray, `y` is computed on the master knowing all the partitions of `d`, and then `u[p]` is updated on each partition knowing `y`. In my attempted implementation, all of `b`, `z`, and `u` are separate RDDs with corresponding keys (e.g. `(1, b[1])`, `(1,z[1])` and `(1, u[1])` correspond to the first partition, etc.).

The problem now with using Spark is that `b` and `z` are extremely large, in the order of GBs. Since RDDs are immutable, whenever I want to "join" them (e.g. bring `z[1]` and `b[1]` onto the same machine for processing) they are replicated i.e. new copies are returned from the numpy arrays. This just multiplies the amount of memory needed, and limits the number of images that can be processed.

I thought a way to avoid the joins is to have an RDD that combines all of variables e.g. `(p, (z[p], b[p], u[p], v[p]))`, but then the immutability problem is still there.

So my question: is there a workaround to update the RDD in place? For example, if I have the RDD as `(p, (z[p], b[p], u[p], v[p]))`, I can update z[p] in-memory?

Comment: try this link https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd

Comment: It's not possible to update an RDD in-place.

Comment: @urug It doesn't seem to be updating in-place, it seems it is also immutable. Right?

Comment: i think you are right. it won't help your case.Apologies.

Comment: No worries. Thanks!